# How read works in fresh mmap (memory mapped) region backed by file?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

> If we perform an anonymous memory mapping then all virtual addresses
>   for that region will point to zero page as the address is not
>   initialized so far. When we tried to read that address it will simply
>   return zero and no page fault will happen. When we tried to write on
>   that address it will cause page fault and subsequently, COW
>   (copy-on-write) will happen.

The above concept is clear to me (correct me if my above understanding is wrong) but what happens in the below scenario.

If we perform a file-backed memory mapping

- what will happen to all virtual addresses for that region, It should not point to zero page, right? as it is not a non-initialized address because the file has the content.
- Will the whole file is loaded into memory in order to initialize the value for the virtual address. If not will page fault will happen for the first read (lol, is this a copy-on-read (COR))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it will page fault as you read the addresses associated with the file but you can set the MAP_POPULATE flag to change this behavior.

The kernel may also attempt to detect that you are reading in a sequential manner (if indeed you are)  and bring in the pages it expects you to need.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41419353) answer is worth reading.

Comment: tnx @icarus, now I can understand.